# How to change Button app:icon property programitically

Tags: java, android, android-button

I have a button with centralized icon+text, and I need to change the `app:icon` and `android:text` properties when some event occurred. I know that there is `setText()` method to change the text, but is there a way to change the icon?

XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bottom_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/bottom_bar_content_vertical_margin"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/light_green"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_next_plan_24"
    app:iconGravity="textStart" />
```

This is a function that is called after appropriate event, and I need to change icon in that function. `icon` and `text` are ids of desirable drawable and string:

```
private void setBottomButton(int icon, int text) {
    button.setText(getString(text));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the methods:

```
setIcon
setIconResource
```

Example:

```
button.setIcon(drawable)
button.setIconResource(iconId)
```

Here the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton#setIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)).

Comment: Thanks. The mistake was the type of the ```button``` variable. It should be ```MaterialButton``` and not just ```Button``` to use ```setIcon``` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the docs, you'll see the code equivalent for each XML attribute.

Check this link : [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)
Searching for drawableLeft shows:

```
android:drawableLeft:
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable,Drawable,Drawable,Drawable)
```

Comment: I need centralized icon. ```drawableLeft``` will put the icon at the left border of button.

Comment: you can set properties ex: gravity this will adjust icon and text in wherever you want, if this won't help, you can use Relativelayout around and add ImageView and TextView combined.